# For what reason certain post removed?

Tags: support

Lost 65 reputation in [my account](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/12418/bala?tab=reputation), certain post were removed without reason.

Is user removed or anything else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Closed question that are extremely off topic, or of very low quality, or may set a precedent about asking a kind of questions, may be removed at the discretion of the community and moderators. Over time, closed questions that are not useful as signposts to other questions may also be removed.

As long as I recall, what it is not expected is you losing reputation, since some of those questions are old enough, and you should not lose reputation you gained on old answers, when old questions are deleted. You still loses reputation gained from suggesting edits, when a post is deleted.

Comment: You don't lose rep if the post has a score of +3 or higher or if the post is older than 60 days.  I think this is still canonical, http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/reputation-and-historical-archives/

Comment: @MPD I'm sure that post's are definitely 60 days older, because I haven't posted anything in that period, suggest me how to fix this

Comment: @Bala I take both the conditions need to be verified, not just one.